# Extends REST_Controller and MY_Controller at once in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, extend, codeigniter-restserver

I have this situation where I need to access a global function and normally I will do that in MY_Controller for the normal CodeIgniter. But in this case, I am using a REST server and I noticed that the normal controller must extends REST_Controller to make it functioning.

**From my AuthController**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';
class AuthController extends REST_Controller {}
```

**REST_Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
abstract class REST_Controller extends CI_Controller {}
```

I want to use `MY_Controller` to create a global function that can be accessed by any controller. For example, from `AuthController` I want to extend it to `MY_Controller`, but by doing so I won't be able to use the `REST_Controller`.

Is there any way I can extend to MY_Controller and REST_Controller at once so that I can use both functions from these two controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Auth controller, extends MY_Controller, and in MY_Controller extends REST_Controller.

It will be like

**AuthController**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class AuthController extends MY_Controller {}
```

**MY_Controller**

```
<?php
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class MY_Controller extends REST_Controller
```

You can write your global functions in your MY_Controller.

Comment: Yeah I did this. Might be too late for the solution but since this is the answer so I accepted it

Comment: Thanks for your acceptance. Glad to hear that you already found the solution.